# How to enable bean validator - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I am consuming data from Kafka into a bean class which has validation to make sure that the message which I am reading is having valid data.

I have added annotations to the bean class, like @NotNull & @Pattern but that is not getting applied.

```java
public class Class {
    @NotNull
    private String field1;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^Open$|^Active$|^Overdue$|^Inactive$")
    private String field2;
}
```

How can I make sure bean validation is applied, I have use @RequestBody @Valid earlier while creating REST services but not sure how to apply in this scenario.

Comment: Did you follow up on the request body attribute with `BindingResult result`. The errors for the bean definition will be in the `BindingResult`. Check if there's any bean error by `result.hasErrors()`

Comment: I would suggest to use avro schemas and let deserializers handle the invalid messages. There is no point in keeping track of validation errors as there is no client to report to.

Comment: @ManishBansal I was using Avro schemas earlier but had to switch custom deserializers where I am implementing kafka client Deserializer class.

Comment: Kafka is used for B2B communication purposes. Either the message is generated by your own some other service or a third party service. Since, its not a user enetered data, in both cases, its a valid data. Why would you want to validate that? You can enter into a contract regarding with the message producers and ignore the message if message cannot be deserialized. Please let me know your usecase here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Programmatic Validation :](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)

Some frameworks – such as Spring – have simple ways of triggering the validation process by just using annotations. This is mainly so that we don’t have to interact with the programmatic validation API.

Let’s now go the manual route and set things up programmatically:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
```

To validate a bean, we must first have a Validator object, which is constructed using a ValidatorFactory.

We’re now going to set up this invalid user – with a null name value:

```
User user = new User();
user.setWorking(true);
user.setAboutMe("Its all about me!");
user.setAge(50);
```

Now that we have a Validator, we can validate our bean by passing it to the validate method. Any violations of the constraints defined in the User object will be returned as a Set.

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);
```

By iterating over the violations, we can get all the violation messages by using the getMessage method.

```
for (ConstraintViolation<User> violation : violations) {
log.error(violation.getMessage()); 
 }
```